# Deadlift as a verb

Tags: translation, english-to-german

The deadlift exercise in German is called Kreuzheben. However, in English there's also the verb "to deadlift". Ex:

> I can deadlift 100 kilograms.

How would you say the same thing in German?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most natural thing to say would probably be

> Ich schaffe 100 kg beim Kreuzheben.

Answer (score 9):

"Kreuzheben" is a compound infinitive like "Bankdrücken". You can construct the verbal back-formation "kreuzheben" and use it as a normal (if somewhat clumsy) verb:

> Ich kann 100 kg kreuzheben.

Comment: Thank you, I suspected as much. I've accepted the other answer as I believe it is the more natural form, but this answer helped too.